# Build (make) lib every time, recompile project only if lib is newer

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following project structure:

```
lib/
    Makefile
    src/...
    inc/...
    build/
        inc/...
        lib/libmylib.a
subproj1/
    src/main.cpp
    Makefile
```

The `Makefile` in the `lib` folder is designed to create the file `libmylib.a` and copy the relevant header files to the `build/inc` folder.

I want the `Makefile` in `subproj1` to always call `make -C ../lib`, but only re-compile file if headers have changed, and re-link only if necessary (one object file or `libmylib.a` is newer).

I have the following (non-defined variables such as `CC` are defined in another file):

```
LIBDIR = ../lib
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
SRCS = $(SRCDIR)/main.cpp

MAIN=myexe

OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.d)

all: $(MAIN)

debug: CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
debug: LFLAGS += -g
debug: $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) $(LIBDIR)/build/lib/libmylib.a
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS) $(LFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(LIBDIR)/build/lib/libmylib.a
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCS) -MD -MF $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $@) $<

$(LIBDIR)/build/lib/libmylib.a:
    make -C $(LIBDIR)

-include $(DEPS)

.PHONY: clean $(LIBDIR)/build/lib/libmylib.a

clean:
    $(RM) obj/* $(MAIN)
```

The above will re-compile `main.cpp` even if nothing has changed in the lib folder. If I remove `$(LIBDIR)/build/lib/libmylib.a` from the `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` rule, the `.cpp` file will not be re-compiled if a header changed (I would need to run `make` twice).

Is there a way to have the `.cpp` files in `subproj1` being compiled only if the header files in `lib` have changed (or if the `.cpp` files themselves have changed), and to get `myexe` built only if one of the `.cpp` has been re-compiled (newer `.o`) or if `libmylib.a` is newer?

Comment: Your auto-generated header dependencies should do the trick, no object file dependency on `.a` should be necessary. Check the target paths in the generated `.d` files, check the output of `make -d`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The problem is that if I remove `libmylib.a` from the `%.o` rule, the `lib` folder is build after the `.cpp` (due to the order of the dependencies in `$(MAIN)`), so the old header files are detected when building `.cpp` (I have to run make twice in this case).

Comment: Since you have a recursive make, just stick in `X:=$(shell ${MAKE} -C ${LIBDIR})` at the top of the file to make sure it is invoked first. This way you do need to mark the `.a` as phony, because it is not phony at all, it is a real file. Then see why the generated header dependencies do not work.

Comment: Correction `X:=`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin This seems to work - Is there a way to see the output of this `make` command in this case?

Comment: `$(info ${X})`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thanks, almost there! Is there any (simple) way to keep the line feeds? Did not found anything easy looking on SO...

Comment: A better command is `$(shell ${MAKE} -C ${LIBDIR} > $$(tty) 2>&1)`. No need to assign to a variable and no buffering.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thanks, perfect! Feel free if you want to make an answer out of this.

Comment: But what about the generated dependencies, do they work as expected now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recursive makefiles you need to execute the sub-project makefiles in correct order because the dependency tree is incomplete (e.g. this makefile does not know that updating `$(LIBDIR)/build/lib/libmylib.a` also updates those headers). It is easy to do that with a shell script or a top-level makefile.

Alternatively, your makefile must execute the sub-makefiles unconditionally in correct order, which can be done with `shell` function, e.g.:

```
LIBDIR := ../lib
pid := $(shell ps -o ppid= $$$$)
$(shell ${MAKE} -C ${LIBDIR} >/proc/$(pid)/fd/1 2>/proc/$(pid)/fd/2)
```

That `$(LIBDIR)/build/lib/libmylib.a` rule should be removed, the object files should not depend on the `.a` and it should not be marked as `.PHONY`.

This makes sure that building in `${LIBDIR}` happens before this makefile analyzes file timestamps in `${LIBDIR}`.

Now your auto-generated header dependencies should just work.

Comment: Can't say I love the idea of invoking a submake via a `$(shell)` in the global scope...  This will not work as expected if the OP runs `make clean` for example, or will not fail if the upper layer makefile fails, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit cleaner.

```
LIBDIR = ../lib
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
SRCS = $(SRCDIR)/main.cpp

MAIN=myexe

OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.d)

all: makelib
    $(MAKE) $(MAIN)

debug: CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
debug: LFLAGS += -g
debug: $(MAIN)

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS) $(LFLAGS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCS) -MD -MF $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $@) $<

makelib:
    make -C $(LIBDIR)

-include $(DEPS)

.PHONY: clean makelib

clean:
    $(RM) obj/* $(MAIN)
```

The main target `all` requires `makelib` to be built, and then it recursively calls itself for the target `$(MAIN)` (so all of `$(MAIN)`'s dependencies will be recalculated after `makelib` has finished building).

Comment: This makefile does not build correctly if the target is specified, e.g. `make myexe` doesn't build its prerequisite. This is because the dependency is missing.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin fair point :-)  Upper level makefile is indeed cleaner.